# what command will it be for this output

Tags: arrays, output

hye, i just new in learning programming.

my lecturer ask to create simple code C language using array that will give below Output:

1  = 1

2  = 1 1

3  =1 1 2

4  =1 1 2 3

5  =1 1 2 3 5

6  =1 1 2 3 5 8

can anyone help me? i have no idea how to create using array for this output.

Comment: Here's [one example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm) (in general, how to write them).

Comment: This is based on Fibonacci serie

Comment: wow Thanks! this will be helpfull